# how to display when i enter user details click submit button error message shown?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

How to solve the above scenario give one example for user object

Comment: Please elaborate! Also update the code what have you tried so far.

Comment: do you have apex:pageMessages component on your VF page?

Comment: plz can u give me the example of user object code